# Elements ignore the Position: Fixed for align in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a problem in HTML and CSS, i have a lateral left menu with a 100% height and position relative. I want to put other elements at the side of it, it is not the problem, the problem is that if I want, for example, center the other element to the center between the menu and the right, I can't do it. It does a center between left and right of the document.

Elements that are in the left of the page are not shown because are behind the menu. How can I indicate that the menu "exists"?

Comment: question is far too broad without being able to see basic layout html and css. Suggest you create a demo in jsfiddle.net that outlines your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just try this:

```
html, body{
    height:100%;
}
body{
    padding-left:400px; /* Suppose the width of sidebar is 400px */
    text-align:center;
    position: relative;
}
.sidebar{
    width:400px;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    position:absolute;
    min-height:600px;
}
```

Comment: It works putting the padding-left in the other divs, 400px in your example. Thanks, it solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You should create another `<div>` for content, set width for it and use `float` or `position` to stick it to the right, then you can put and center all your content or everything you want in this particular block